# Comparing all elements of a list to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a program that can index the reads of a FASTQ file and run a QC on the barcodes attached to each read. I am using a dictionary to store the indices using the barcode as key - the corresponding value is a list of lists where the indices are kept. A barcode is an 8 character string containing the letters A, T, G, and C.

A read looks like this with a header, sequence, +, and another sequence:

@ST-K00127:119:HF2FVBBXX:8:1101:31253:1595 1:N:0:TCTTCACA
TTTTTCATTGATCTGTCGCAAGGCTTCCTCCGCTGTACCGTTTAACTTGAATTCCATTACGTAAATAAATCTGTCTGTC
+
AAAFFJJFJJJJJFJJJ

And a dictionary element could look like this: 
key: TCTTCACA value: [[0,350], [351,500]]

Now I am trying to run a function that measures edit distance between two barcodes and I want to do this for each barcode against all other barcodes in the dictionary. I am creating an upper triangle matrix storing all the edit distances and then I am finding the number of positions where the edit distance is equal to 1 or 2. The problem is that I keep getting differing numbers of positions unless I sort the list of keys beforehand, which in my humble opinion should not make a difference as all elements are still being compared to each other no matter the order of the list. Can someone help me? I am wondering whether it is my code or if there is soomething going on behind the scenes that I don't know of.

Code example:

```
key_list = list(barcode_index.keys())
N = len(key_list)
barcode_matrix = np.zeros((N, N)) 
for i in range(N)):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        barcode_matrix[i,j] = calculate_distance(key_list[i], key_list[j])
error_barcodes1 = np.where(barcode_matrix==1)
error_barcodes2 = np.where(barcode_matrix==2)

def calculate_distance(barcode1, barcode2):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(0,8):
        if barcode1[i] != barcode2[i]:
            distance += 1
    return distance
```

Comment: Are you sure that the number of 1's and 2's is changing, and not just their positions? The order of the keys may not be deterministic, but you are correct in that it shouldn't matter for the counts themselves.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provided example data which produces the error in question.

Comment: And, finally, is each entry in `barcode` a `list`? If not, the equality check may not be working as you'd expect.

Comment: When I print the length of error_barcodes1 and error_barcodes2 I get different numbers all the time. I would say that they both differ in the magnitude of +/-50. The key_list is a list of 1074 different keys - a small excerpt: 
AGATGTAC
ATAGCGAC
CAAGACTA
AGCACCTC
TGGTGGTA
CGGATTGC
AGCCATGC
TCTTCACA
CGACTGGA
CCATCCTC
TGGCTTCA
CCTCGGTA
CTGGCATA
CTCAATGA
TGAAGAGA
CTGAGCCA
CCTCTATC
GAGCTGAA
TAGTGGTA
CACTTCGA
AGGCTAAC
CACCTTAC
GCTCGGTA
CGCATACA
Not sure what you mean with the third comment - do you mean the barcode_matrix? Or the barcodes calculate_distance()?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, so if you can't provide data which reproduces the problem, I can't do much to help you.

Comment: So it turns out that it was not the code but a problem with the interpreter (I guess). I switched and now I get the same numbers consistently. Thanks for your time, @JaredGoguen :-)